# Insert hot-swappable disks into a running server?

Tags: hard-drive, dell, dell-poweredge, dell-openmanage, dell-perc

I have a Dell PowerEdge 2900 with a PERC 6/i card and 4 HDDs running a single RAID-10 array. I want to add an additional 4 HDDs into the server and create a new RAID-10 array on those disks, without having to power-down the server. There's an option in OpenManage to create a virtual disk, so I'm guess after inserting the disks I would create the VD through there, but wondered if all this can be done while the server is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a hot-plug backplane and controller, yes, that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That's why they are called hot-swap drives.